# ¿Hay alguna forma de superponer un widget sobre otros?

Tags: python, tkinter

¿Hay alguna forma de superponer un widget sobre otros, sin alterar el orden del código?

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Listbox
from tkinter import Label
ventana = Tk()

label = Label(ventana)
label.config(text="Test")
label.place(x=50,y=50)

list = Listbox(ventana)
list.config(width=50,height=30)
list.place(x=30,y=30)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`place` simplemente posiciona y apila según el orden de instancia de los widgets con ese mismo padre, sin aceptar ningún parámetro que permita definir el orden o nivel dentro de la pila. No obstante, si que hay dos métodos que permiten cambiar dicho orden a posteridad:

- `widget.lift(aboveThis=None)`: eleva el widget/ventana en el orden de apilamiento con respecto a sus widgets hermanos (mismo padre).
- `widget.lower(aboveThis=None)`: baja el widget/ventana en el orden de apilamiento con respecto a sus widgets hermanos (mismo padre).

En ambos casos si omite el argumento `aboveThis`, el widget/ventana se coloca de modo que esté por encima (`lift`) / por debajo (`lower`) de todos sus hermanos en el orden de apilamiento. Si se especifica una referencia/nombre a un widget hermano o descendiente de un widget hermano se insertará en el orden de apilamiento justo arriba (`lift`) / debajo (`lower`) del widget especificado.

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry("300x400")
frame_rojo = tk.Frame(ventana, bg="red")
frame_verde = tk.Frame(ventana, bg="green")
frame_azul = tk.Frame(ventana, bg="blue")
frame_rojo.place(x=50, y=50, height=200, width=200)
frame_verde.place(x=70, y=70, height=200, width=200)
frame_azul.place(x=90, y=90, height=200, width=200)

tk.Button(ventana, text="Rojo  arriba", command=frame_rojo.lift).place(x=100, y=300)
tk.Button(ventana, text="Rojo   abajo", command=frame_rojo.lower).place(x=100, y=350)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Si le pasas el nombre o referencia de otro widget se posiciona encima o debajo de este como se ha comentado. Por ejemplo, en tu caso puedes colocar el `Label` encima del `ListBox`:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Listbox
from tkinter import Label


ventana = Tk()

label = Label(ventana)
label.config(text="Test")
label.place(x=50,y=50)

listbox = Listbox(ventana)
listbox.config(width=50,height=30)
listbox.place(x=30,y=30)
label.lift(listbox)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola, por que no funciona con este tipo de listbox? Mi codigo: https://pastebin.com/sfhajMg1                                                                                                                             PD: ¿Como sabes tanto?, estas en casi todos los posts del sitio, ¿hiciste alguna carrera, formación personal o mezcla de ambas?, saludos.

Comment: Hola Franco, el problema es que llamas al método `lift` mediante la clase (`Entry`) y no mediante la instancia (`entry`), es decir, en vez de `Entry.lift(lb)` debe ser `entry.lift(lb)`, la "E" inicial en minúscula (que es como llamas a tu instancia de Entry en  `entry = Entry(ventana)`), supongo que es un simple typo.

Comment: En cuanto a lo segundo,tampoco exageres,si soy muy activo en Python y puntualmente en C, C++ y Rust pero no en todo el sitio XD. Pues en lo referente a Python casi todo es formación personal realmente, aunque empezó todo con la necesidad de usarlo para análisis de datos en el ámbito científico cuando Python no era tan popular como lo es hoy , luego pasó también a ser un hobby  y aquí estamos... Ahora ando metiendo mis narices en  Rust también por hobby y por la posibilidad de combinarlo con Python reemplazando a C/C++ dónde la eficiencia sea crítica. A ver si algún día también se populariza XD

Comment: Bueno capaz con lo del todo el sitio me pase un poco xD, pero en casi todos los post de python si estas. Aun no me funciona con el código original :( es este: https://pastebin.com/RS3d2gqK y me sale esto: self.tk.call('raise', self._w, aboveThis)
_tkinter.TclError: can't raise ".!crearframe.!label" above ".!editlistbox"

Comment: En el `__init__` de la clase `editlistBox`, a la hora de llamar al constructor de la clase padre te has olvidado de pasar la referencia al widget padre, en vez de `Listbox.__init__(self, width=ancho,height=alto)` debe ser `Listbox.__init__(self, ventana, width=ancho, height=alto)` o `super().__init__(ventana, width=ancho, height=alto)`. Al no pasar el widget padre `self.listBox` y `self.label1` tienen distinto padre por lo que `lift` no se puede aplicar.